# Multiplicity of an holomorphic map between Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I need help understanding the meaning of *multiplicity in a point* of an holomorphic map between Riemann sufaces. So $F\colon X \to Y$ be an holomorphic, not constant map between Riemann surfaces and fix $p\in X$.

We know that it is possible to find local charts $(U,\phi), (V,\psi)$ centered in $p$ and in $F(p)$ respectively such that the local expression $f:=\psi\circ F\circ \phi^{-1}$ is $z\mapsto z^m$ for an integer $m$. It is possible to prove that this $m$ does not depend on the choice of the charts and it is called *multiplicity* of  $F$ in $p$.

Now, what is the meaning of this $m$? I think that $m$ indicates the number of preimages in $X$ near $p$. More precisely, if  $(U,\phi), (V,\psi)$ are local charts centered in $p$ and in $F(p)$ respectively, if $m=mult_p(F)$, then for each $y\in V\cap \text{Im} F$ there are exactly $m$ preimages in $U$. Is it correct or am I missing something?
So it is intuitively true that the definition of multeplicity does not depend on the charts, but only on $p$ and $F$.

Answer (score 1):

You need some extra assumptions:$f$ not constant on any component of $X$,  $Y$ connected, ($X$ compact, or some behavior  of $f$ at infinity if $X$ not compact). The degree of the map $f\colon X \to Y$ is a positive integer $m$ so that:

for every $y$ in $Y$ the equation $f(x)=y$ has exactly $m$ solutions $x \in X$ ( counting multiplicities). The fact that this number is constant is a theorem. 
There will be just finitely many points $y$ in $Y$ for which the multiplicities of some roots are $>1$.

A basic example is the map $z \mapsto z^m$ from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ or even better, from $\hat{ \mathbb{C}}$ to $\hat{ \mathbb{C}}$.  Another important example are polynomial maps of degree $m\ $ 
$$z \mapsto a_m z^m + \ldots + a_0$$

Comment: So you are sating that the multiplicity of an holomorphic, not costant map does not depend on the point $x\in X$?

Comment: The sum of the multiplicities at points in any fiber is constant. You group together all the $x$ that map to the same value and then sum up the multiplicities. The multiplicity at different points $x$ may surely vary.

Comment: Ok, you are reffering to the degree of a holomorphic map, not to the multiplicity, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't recognize in your answer the definition I have for *multiplicity* in $p$ of an holomorphic map: that is $m\in \mathbb Z$ such that there exist centered local charts $(U,\phi)$ in $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ in $F(p)$ such that the local expression of $F$ in these charts is $z\mapsto z^m$.

Comment: Yes, the definition of multiplicity basically what you are stating. I confused it with the degree.

Comment: So is it true that if $mult_p(F)=m$ then each point "near" $F(p)$ in the image of $F$ has exactly $m$ preimages near $p$?

Comment: Yes, near $F(p)$ and not $F(p)$. Thus the multiplicity can be expressed only in terms of the topology. In fact, if you eliminate $p$ from the domain and $F(p)$ from the target it's a covering map of degree $m$.

Comment: You should really call it the multiplicity of a map at a certain point, not the multiplicity of a map.

Comment: I've edited my post, hoping that now it is more clear. But when you say "near $F(p)$ and not F(p)", what do you mean? Do you mean that $F(p)$ has not $m=mult_p(F)$ preimages near $p$? why?

Comment: Set theoretically $F(p)$ has exactly one preimage around $p$ and that is $p$. If you want to say: $p$ with multiplicity $m$, you are getting into a circular definition.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. But isn't it possible that around $p$ there exists $q\neq p$ such that $F(q)=F(p)$?

Comment: No, since locally the map looks like $z\mapsto z^m$ and $p$ correponds to $0$, $F(p)$ also corresponds to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, let's assume X and Y compacts. Then, $\, f : X \longrightarrow Y$ is a branched covering. Which means that expect over a finite number of points $A = \{y_0, \ldots, y_n \} \subset Y$, $f : X \backslash f^{-1}(A) \longrightarrow Y \backslash A$ is a covering map. Then the multiplicity is exactly the degree of this covering map: the number of sheets over a point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't even know what a branched covering is.

Answer (score 0):

You are right: m indicates the number of pre-images of $f$ in X near p, counted with multiplicity. As you write, locally $f$ equals the m-th power $z\mapsto z^m$. Hence each point from $V$ different from zero has exactly $m$ different roots in $U$. All roots come together in the singleton $\{0\}$ containing the unique root of $0$ with multiplicity $m$.

Comment: there exist centered local charts $(U,\phi)$ in $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ in $F(p)$ such that the local expression of $F$ in these charts is $z↦z^m$. But for any $y\in\psi(V)$ why there are exactly m preimages in the domain of $\psi\circ F\circ\phi^{-1}$?

Comment: I am saying that number of  preimages should be less than or equal to $m$.